# In document click how to find target in checkbox?

Tags: jquery

How to find target is checkbox ?

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // Do things
});
```

how to find this ? if it's check box not need to proceed this events ?

Comment: What do you mean by "find target in checkbox"?

Comment: @Blender i'm means clicked object

Comment: have you tried learning javascript ?

Comment: Because you obviously spent less time on google, researching this, then it too you to write this "question".

Comment: @tereško anything wrong in my question ?

Comment: @tereško  it may helpful to use for others that's i'm posted . it got 5 different answers . also everyone clearly informed advantage and disadvantage . i hats off to every one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect click on all elements (`*`) so you can use `$(this)`.

```
$("*").on("click", function (e) {

    if ($(this).attr("type") === "checkbox") {
        alert("Checkbox click!");
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WABdP/1)

If you want to detect clicks **only** on checkboxes use `input[type='checkbox']` selector.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Like @XAOPT said we also can detect the clicks on `document` and then verifying if it's a checkbox using `e.srcElement`.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {    
    if(e.srcElement == "checkbox") { 
        alert("Checkbox click!");
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WABdP/2/)

Comment: The first suggestion (using `$('*')`) is a really bad idea. If it's on a large page, that can take a long time to get through every element. You're much better off using what you already have than that. The second part was already suggested 3 minutes before by @Derek 朕會功夫.

Comment: @kalley But it answer to what OP asked: he wants to find if the **clicked** element is checkbox. This means that we have to detect clicks on elements, and then to verify: "is it really a checkbox or not?"

Comment: Then I would say that @XAOPT answer is better since it does the same thing and doesn't attach unnecessary click events to every element.

Answer (score 2):

or

```
$(document).click(function(e) {    
    if(e.srcElement.type == 'checkbox') 
        alert('checkbox');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
    // do things
});
```

Unless there's a reason you need a generic click on the document and do the delegation yourself...

Comment: `:checkbox` isn't a native selector, so you may want to use `input[type="checkbox"]`.

Comment: @Blender - You mean `checkbox` right?

Comment: @Blender if you want to get picky about performance, then yes `input[type="checkbox"]` will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector can do that for you:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){

});